# How to set ripple effect on android version 4.4?

Tags: android

I am trying to set ripple effect on button android version 4.4, but application getting crash.

Comment: Either you can create your custom ripple effect in this folder res->values-21->ripple.xml (refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/27529637/4906130) or you can use third party library for that https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect, https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example: https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView

Good look!

Comment: you should post some sample code and some explanations to your posts