# how do I change the solid color of a ripple drawable?

Tags: android, rippledrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_selected="true">
                <layer-list>
                    <item android:left="-5dp"
                          android:top="-5dp"
                          android:right="-5dp">
                        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                            <stroke android:width="3dp"
                                    android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                        </shape>
                    </item>
                </layer-list>
            </item>
            <item android:state_selected="false">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

here is my ripple drawable and i want to change the **state_selected**, **solid** color.

code i've tried:

```
RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) textView.getBackground(); // assumes bg is a RippleDrawable
        int[][] states = new int[][]{new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}};
        int[] colors = new int[]{R.color.white}; 
        ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
        rippleDrawable.setColor(colorStateList);
```

unfortuantely it doesn't work.. what am I missing and is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967872/create-a-ripple-drawable-without-transparency use a mask.

Answer (score 5):

You should add an id to items to access them via java/kotlin.
check this background XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#e0e0e0">
   <item android:id="@+id/fab_shape">
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:shape="rectangle">
         <corners android:radius="25dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
     </shape>
  </item>
</ripple>
```

to change the solid color of this, on constraintLayout background, this drawable XML is applied

```
val background = constraintLayout.background as RippleDrawable
val bgShape = background.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.fab_shape) as GradientDrawable
bgShape.color = color
```

for reference [read this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12681/programmatically-change-the-solid-color-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. I have a very similar code and it works fine:

```
val background = textView.background!!.mutate() as RippleDrawable
background.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(0xffff0000.toInt()))
textView.background = background
```

Try it.

I've made an easier function too:

```
fun View.setBackgroundTintColor(@ColorInt color: Int) {
    val background = background
    if (background is RippleDrawable) {
        val newBackground = background.mutate() as RippleDrawable
        newBackground.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
        this.background = newBackground
    } else ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(color))
}
```